# Flask JSON Custom Error Page

Tags: python, flask

is there any implementation exists on JSON as custom error page on Flask?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you need... Please try to clarify your answer so your problem can be better understood. What do you need? What have you tried?

Answer (score 30):

You can create a json response object using the "jsonify" helper from flask and then set the status_code of the response before returning it like this:

```
def not_found(error):
    response = jsonify({'code': 404,'message': 'No interface defined for URL'})
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

You can register this function as the handler by wrapping it in the errorhandler:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    ...
```

OR, setting it directly on the error_handler_spec:

```
app.error_handler_spec[None][404] = not_found
```

Comment: Clear and helpful, highlighted the fact that jsonify returns a response object, which I had forgotten. It also seems to cover any possible interpretation of the asker's question.